# lspci does not return any results

Tags: drivers, lspci

Whenever I run the `lspci` command on my system (dell xps15 cnx95604 running Ubuntu 16.04) it doesn't return any results, nor can I kill the process. In some cases it even crashes the system.

Output of `journalctl -f` before running `lspci` (it displays multiple of these messages):

```
Feb 06 16:26:21 lenny kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e0
Feb 06 16:26:21 lenny kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, id=00e0(Transmitter ID)
Feb 06 16:26:21 lenny kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:   device [8086:a110] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
Feb 06 16:26:21 lenny kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:    [12] Replay Timer Timeout
```

Output of `journalctl -f` while running `lspci`:

```
Feb 06 16:27:51 lenny kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
Feb 06 16:27:51 lenny kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
Feb 06 16:27:51 lenny kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
Feb 06 16:27:51 lenny kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming object tree...
```

Afterwards, the system crashed.

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

**EDIT:**
I have tried it again, and this time got the following output:

```
Feb 06 17:06:58 lenny kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
Feb 06 17:06:58 lenny kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
Feb 06 17:06:58 lenny kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
Feb 06 17:06:58 lenny kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming object tree...
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel: watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 22s! [kworker/1:1:58]
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel: Modules linked in: ccm rfcomm ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 nf_conntrack_netlink nfnetlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo iptable_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_nat_ipv4 xt_addrtype iptable_filter ip_tables xt_conntrack x_tables nf_nat nf_conntrack libcrc32c br_netfilter bridge stp llc overlay bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic arc4 nls_iso8859_1 hid_multitouch dell_laptop intel_rapl dell_smm_hwmon x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec kvm_intel snd_hda_core snd_hwdep kvm snd_pcm ath10k_pci ath10k_core irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel ath pcbc mac80211 snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event rtsx_pci_ms memstick snd_rawmidi aesni_intel cfg80211 aes_x86_64 snd_seq crypto_simd glue_helper cryptd
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel:  intel_cstate intel_rapl_perf uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core videodev snd_seq_device snd_timer media joydev input_leds serio_raw idma64 snd virt_dma dell_wmi dell_smbios btusb mei_me dcdbas processor_thermal_device wmi_bmof soundcore btrtl mei intel_lpss_pci intel_pch_thermal intel_soc_dts_iosf shpchp hci_uart btbcm serdev btqca btintel bluetooth dell_smo8800 ecdh_generic intel_lpss_acpi int3403_thermal intel_lpss int340x_thermal_zone tpm_crb int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel intel_hid acpi_pad sparse_keymap mac_hid acpi_als kfifo_buf industrialio parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 hid_generic usbhid nouveau i915 rtsx_pci_sdmmc mxm_wmi ttm i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea nvme sysfillrect psmouse sysimgblt fb_sys_fops ahci drm nvme_core
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel:  rtsx_pci libahci i2c_hid hid pinctrl_sunrisepoint wmi video pinctrl_intel
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel: CPU: 1 PID: 58 Comm: kworker/1:1 Not tainted 4.13.0-32-generic #35~16.04.1-Ubuntu
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel: Hardware name: Dell Inc. XPS 15 9560/05FFDN, BIOS 1.5.0 08/30/2017
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel: Workqueue: pm pm_runtime_work
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel: task: ffff9988eb6edf00 task.stack: ffffa5c901b0c000
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel: RIP: 0010:ioread32+0x30/0x40
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffa5c901b0fb58 EFLAGS: 00000296 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffff10
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel: RAX: 00000000ffffffff RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 0000000000000018
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel: RDX: 00276420498a19d3 RSI: ffffa5c90410a014 RDI: ffffa5c90410a04c
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel: RBP: ffffa5c901b0fb88 R08: 0000000000000130 R09: ffffa5c901b0fb2c
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 00000000000003b8 R12: ffff9988e0a76800
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel: R13: ffff9988e0830d20 R14: ffffffffffffffff R15: ffff9988e199be40
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel: FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9988fe440000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel: CR2: 00003e562e96a000 CR3: 000000020d80a005 CR4: 00000000003606e0
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel: Call Trace:
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel:  ? nvkm_pmu_reset+0x94/0x170 [nouveau]
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel:  nvkm_pmu_preinit+0x12/0x20 [nouveau]
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel:  nvkm_subdev_preinit+0x34/0x110 [nouveau]
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel:  nvkm_device_init+0x61/0x280 [nouveau]
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel:  nvkm_udevice_init+0x48/0x60 [nouveau]
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel:  nvkm_object_init+0x40/0x190 [nouveau]
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel:  nvkm_object_init+0xb4/0x190 [nouveau]
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel:  nvkm_client_resume+0xe/0x10 [nouveau]
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel:  nvif_client_resume+0x17/0x20 [nouveau]
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel:  nouveau_do_resume+0x40/0xe0 [nouveau]
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel:  nouveau_pmops_runtime_resume+0x8c/0x170 [nouveau]
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel:  ? pci_restore_standard_config+0x50/0x50
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel:  pci_pm_runtime_resume+0x76/0xa0
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel:  __rpm_callback+0xc4/0x200
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel:  ? pci_restore_standard_config+0x50/0x50
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel:  rpm_callback+0x24/0x80
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel:  ? pci_restore_standard_config+0x50/0x50
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel:  rpm_resume+0x4b3/0x6c0
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel:  pm_runtime_work+0x55/0xa0
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel:  process_one_work+0x156/0x410
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel:  worker_thread+0x4b/0x460
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel:  kthread+0x109/0x140
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel:  ? process_one_work+0x410/0x410
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel:  ? kthread_create_on_node+0x70/0x70
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel:  ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x30
Feb 06 17:07:25 lenny kernel: Code: 03 00 77 25 48 81 ff 00 00 01 00 76 05 0f b7 d7 ed c3 55 48 c7 c6 cf c8 ee ad 48 89 e5 e8 29 ff ff ff b8 ff ff ff ff 5d c3 8b 07 <c3> 0f 1f 44 00 00 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 48 81 fe ff ff 
Feb 06 17:07:46 lenny org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer[2004]: ** (zeitgeist-fts:3147): WARNING **: Unable to get info on application://nautilus-autostart.desktop
Feb 06 17:07:53 lenny kernel: watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 22s! [kworker/1:1:58]
Feb 06 17:07:53 lenny kernel: Modules linked in: ccm rfcomm ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 nf_conntrack_netlink nfnetlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo iptable_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_nat_ipv4 xt_addrtype iptable_filter ip_tables xt_conntrack x_tables nf_nat nf_conntrack libcrc32c br_netfilter bridge stp llc overlay bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic arc4 nls_iso8859_1 hid_multitouch dell_laptop intel_rapl dell_smm_hwmon x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec kvm_intel snd_hda_core snd_hwdep kvm snd_pcm ath10k_pci ath10k_core irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel ath pcbc mac80211 snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event rtsx_pci_ms memstick snd_rawmidi aesni_intel cfg80211 aes_x86_64 snd_seq crypto_simd glue_helper cryptd
Feb 06 17:07:53 lenny kernel:  intel_cstate intel_rapl_perf uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core videodev snd_seq_device snd_timer media joydev input_leds serio_raw idma64 snd virt_dma dell_wmi dell_smbios btusb mei_me dcdbas processor_thermal_device wmi_bmof soundcore btrtl mei intel_lpss_pci intel_pch_thermal intel_soc_dts_iosf shpchp hci_uart btbcm serdev btqca btintel bluetooth dell_smo8800 ecdh_generic intel_lpss_acpi int3403_thermal intel_lpss int340x_thermal_zone tpm_crb int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel intel_hid acpi_pad sparse_keymap mac_hid acpi_als kfifo_buf industrialio parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 hid_generic usbhid nouveau i915 rtsx_pci_sdmmc mxm_wmi ttm i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea nvme sysfillrect psmouse sysimgblt fb_sys_fops ahci drm nvme_core
```

From this point onwards it just repeats over and over again.